# Why is plot_model raising an assertion error for displaying this neural network?

Tags: python, keras, graphviz, pydot

I was just testing keras neural networks, and I wanted to visualize my neural network. I followed a code example from a website, however the code raises and AssertionError -9.
Here's the code.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(4, input_shape=(2,), activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(3, input_shape=(4,), activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(1))

plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

This is the error message.
[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yDDo.png)

Really appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: I think you might need `pip install pydot` and possibly `pip install graphviz`

Comment: I have installed them both.

Comment: tried your code in google colab it worked , you got depednecies issue try pip install -u graphviz